# How to send backend page load time(speed) to google analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

Currently I am sending analytics data with standard way from us

```
ga('create', 'UA-57076138-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'GTM-WXZ87G8');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

behind the scene I have php framework and I measure all page loads e.g.

```
$start = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
//framework entry point 
//match route
//controller call
//render view
//end of framework execution
$end = (round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $start);
```

Now I want to send this time to analytics something like

```
ga('sendBackendTime', '<?php echo $end; ?>');
```

And with this collected page speeds I want to know when some deploy(commit) increased page load time and for which pages.

Is google analytic good tool for measurements like this one ?
If yes, how I can send this data and then analyze at analytics administration ?

Comment: i believe you can use `ga('send', 'timing', [timingCategory], [timingVar], [timingValue], [timingLabel], [fieldsObject]);`  read ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings) should explain it al.

Comment: Timing hits are sampled (in a free account I think 1% of the traffic, or 10 000 hits a day, whatever happens first).  So this would mean a custom metric for unsampled reports (but you cannot break down by metric, you'd get a total and from that could calculate averages) or a custom dimension (in which case you probably want to send buckets rather than individual values, else this will be almost impossible to get a report out if it).